# Boundedness of scalar curvature gives boundedness of sectional curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(X,\omega)$ be a compact Kahler manifold which the scalar curvature is bounded then the sectional curvature is bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a compact manifold $M$ with metric of class $C^{2}$, the sectional curvature is bounded without qualification, since the sectional curvature may be viewed as a continuous, real-valued function on the bundle of oriented $2$-planes in the tangent bundle $TM$, and this Grassmann bundle is compact if $M$ is compact.

Comment: what about non-compact case?

Comment: In the general Riemannian case, bounded scalar curvature obviously does not imply bounded sectional curvature: Take a warped product of a disk and a $2$-sphere where the disk's curvature is unbounded below and the sphere's radius is chosen to make the scalar curvature constant. Offhand I can't construct a Kähler example, however.